# change sort index of list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list like

```
[
  0:a,
  1:b,
  2:c,
  3:d,
]
```

I want change position between 0 and 2 to like that

```
[
  0:c,
  1:b,
  2:a,
  3:d,
]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you trying to accomplish and is not working?

Comment: exactly you need some kind of sorting or just change two index with each other?

Comment: @Ezra I want change positions between to element inside list

Comment: @Majid how change two index with each other

Comment: do you need a list or a map?

Comment: @Doc I need a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main() {
  var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

  print(arr);

  var c = arr.removeAt(2);
  var a = arr.removeAt(0);

  arr.insert(0, c);
  arr.insert(2, a);
  print(arr);
}
```

Try on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)